# Use of select in c++ to do a timeout in a protocol to transfer files over serial port

Tags: c++, c, serial-port

I have a function to write data to the serial port with a certain protocol. When the function writes one frame, it waits for one answer of receiver. If no answer is received it has to resend data during 3 timeouts and in the end of 3 timeouts with no success, close the communication...

I have this function:

```
int serial_write(int fd, unsigned char* send, size_t send_size) { 

......


        int received_counter = 0;
        while (!RECEIVED) {
            Timeout.tv_usec = 0;  // milliseconds
            Timeout.tv_sec  = timeout;  // seconds
            FD_SET(fd, &readfs);
            //set testing for source 1

            res = select(fd + 1, &readfs, NULL, NULL, &Timeout);
            //timeout occurred.

            if (received_counter == 3) {
                printf(
                        "Connection maybe turned off! Number of resends exceeded!\n");
                exit(-1);
            }

            if (res == 0) {
                printf("Timeout occured\n");
                write(fd, (&I[0]), I.size());
                numTimeOuts++;
                received_counter++;

            } else {
                RECEIVED = true;
                break;
            }

        }

......

}
```

I have verified that this function, when it goes into timeout, does not resend the data.  Why?

Comment: What do you expect to automagically resend data?

Comment: What is the variable(?) `I`? And you should check the `write` call for errors.

Comment: Variable I, is a vector of unsigned char with a vector that i want send. 
I Resend data when i dont get a answer of my destination serial port

Comment: What I mean by checking the `write` call for errors, is that you should check what `write` returns. If it's `-1` then `write` failed, and you should check [`errno`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/errno) to see what went wrong. You could also use [`strerror`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror) to get a nicer error message you can print.

Comment: ...or use `perror` instead or `strerror`

Comment: All in all, the code seems okay. If the `write` calls succeed then you need to check the cabling, and, more importantly, that the other side actually works the way it's intended.